# Generating Crystal Report by month?

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I have a mComboBox which have the list of the month names. and i have a sql table

```
InstallmentTable
    ID
    CurrentMonth
    Installment
    Commission
```

I want to generate crystal report where **CurrentMonth = mComboBoxSelectedMonth** I'm beginner in crystal reports kindly guide me how can i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be two ways to do this thing

1) Firstly you have to filter the data table with respect combo value at front end and reassign the filtered data table to crystal report by using SetDataSource() function.

2) Secondly you can do by filtering the record at database end as per your combo value and then re assign new data table to crystal.

There is no direct way of filtering the records at crystal report level.

Answer (score 1):

Use the selection formula in your report....

```
{dailysummary2.date} >= cdate(year(currentdate),(Month ({?startdate})),1)
```

and

```
{dailysummary2.date} < dateserial(year(currentdate),(Month ({?startdate}))+1,1)
```

Comment: Why do you use `cdate` in your `>=` comparison, but `dateserial` in your `<` comparison? Can't you use the same in both? (Note that I'm not saying it won't work.)